# Why would adding an **appSettings** section to App.config cause an error in WPF application?

Tags: .net, wpf, prism, app-config

In my WPF application (Composite Application) I want to store a variable in the **App.config** file, but as soon as I add an **appSettings** section in App.config, it gives me this error:

> The type initializer for
>   System.Windows.Application threw an
>   exception.

**App.Config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
      <appSettings>
          <add key="SmartFormMockDirectory" value="C:\test"/>
      </appSettings>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="Service1Soap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTime...
```

In general I know this works [since I can get it to work in simple applications like this](http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=howtos&id=20).

**What could be causing the above error and how would I fix it so I can simply add variables to the App.config file?**

Comment: With Type Initializer exceptions, you should try and interrogate for an InnerException.  There usually is one.  In this case it would have given you a better answer.  Andrew is very likely correct, though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It seems to be complaining that you have placed your `<appSettings>` node above the `<configSections>` node.  Either move the `<configSections>` node to the top to be the first element in the file or remove it (as you don't seem to be using it).

From [`configSections` Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228256.aspx):

> If the configSections element is in a
>   configuration file, the configSections
>   element must be the first child
>   element of the configuration element.

Comment: This was driving me nuts! Putting configSections as the very first element even about <startup> solved it.

Comment: I had a duplicate `appSettings` tag. Removing the duplicate fixed this for me.